# Different batching behavior between React event and useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, batching

As far as I know, React 18 will auto-batch state updates to reduce re-render (including updates inside of timeouts, promises...), e.g.

```
    function handleClick() {
        setCount(c => c + 1); // Does not re-render yet
        setFlag(f => !f); // Does not re-render yet
        // React will only re-render once at the end (that's batching!)
    }
```

```
    fetch(/*...*/).then(() => {
        setCount(c => c + 1);
        setFlag(f => !f);
        // React will only re-render once at the end (that's batching!)
    })
```

but batch will not applies to different timeouts/promises, e.g.

```
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const resA = await fetch('...').then(res => res.json()).then(data => data);
        setA(resA);
        const resB = await fetch('...').then(res => res.json()).then(data => data);
        setB(resB);
        // this will end up having two re-renders
    }
```

This is why I usually intentionally batch state updates like this:

```
    const fetchData = async () => {
        const resA = await fetch('...').then(res => res.json()).then(data => data);
        const resB = await fetch('...').then(res => res.json()).then(data => data);
        setA(resA);
        setB(resB);
        // this works, only one re-render
    }
```

but I recently came upon this inconsistent batching behavior between React event and useEffect, here's the experiment code:[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-mayer-7mrj56?file=/src/components/Test.js)
Note:strictMode is commented out.

```
    // ContextProvider.js
    const initialState = {
        a: null,
        b: null,
        c: null,
        d: null,
        e: null
    }
    const testReducer = (state, action) => {
        switch(action.type) {
            case 'capitalA' : {
                return {
                    ...state, a: "A"
                }
            }
            case 'capitalB' : {
                return {
                    ...state, b: "B"
                }
            }
            case 'capitalC' : {
                return {
                    ...state, c: "C"
                }
            }
            case 'capitalD' : {
                return {
                    ...state, d: "D"
                }
            }
            case 'capitalE' : {
                return {
                    ...state, e: "E"
                }
            }
            default : {
                return state;
            }
        }
    }
```

```
    // Test.js
    export default function Test() {
        const state = useStateContext();
        const dispatch = useDispatchContext();
        console.log(state)

        const asyncCapitalFunc = async letter => {
            dispatch({type: `capital${letter}`});
        };

        const batchTest = async () => {
            await asyncCapitalFunc('A');
            await asyncCapitalFunc('B');
        };

        return (
            <>
            <p>{state.count}</p>
            <button onClick={() => batchTest()}>Click</button>
            </>
        )
    };
```

results:

```
    const batchTest = async () => {
        await asyncCapitalFunc('A');
        await asyncCapitalFunc('B');
        dispatch({type: 'capitalC'});
    };
```

The above code: One click causes three re-renders, which is as expected.
[click result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZScA.png)

```
    const batchTest = async () => {
        dispatch({type: 'capitalC'});
        await asyncCapitalFunc('A');
        await asyncCapitalFunc('B');
    };
```

The above code: One click causes two re-renders, also as expected, the first await call is batched together with the regular dispatch above it.
[click result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z672Z.png)

```
    const batchTest = async () => {
        dispatch({type: 'capitalC'});
        await asyncCapitalFunc('A');
        await asyncCapitalFunc('B');
        await asyncCapitalFunc('D');
        await asyncCapitalFunc('E');
    };
```

The above code: One click causes four re-renders, still as expected.
[click result 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCMho.png)

```
    const batchTest = async () => {
        await asyncCapitalFunc('A');
        await asyncCapitalFunc('B');
        dispatch({type: 'capitalC'});
        await asyncCapitalFunc('D');
        await asyncCapitalFunc('E');
    };
```

The above code: One click causes four re-renders, still as expected.
[click result 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeuHB.png)

----------------------now let’s switch the same code to Effect------------------

```
    import { useStateContext, useDispatchContext } from "./ContextProvider"
    import { useEffect } from "react";

        export default function Test() {
        const state = useStateContext();
        const dispatch = useDispatchContext();
        console.log(state)

        useEffect(()=> {
            const asyncCapitalFunc = async letter => {
                dispatch({type: `capital${letter}`});
            };

            const batchTest = async () => {
                await asyncCapitalFunc('A');
                await asyncCapitalFunc('B');
            };
        batchTest()
        }, [dispatch]);

        return (
            <>
            <p>{state.count}</p>
            </>
        )
    };
```

results:

```
    const batchTest = async () => {
        await asyncCapitalFunc('A');
        await asyncCapitalFunc('B');
        dispatch({type: 'capitalC'});
    };
```

The above code: In addition to the initial render, there’re two re-renders, and the second await call is batched together with the dispatch below it, which is not the same as what happens in a click event.
[Effect result1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrQVb.png)

```
    const batchTest = async () => {
        dispatch({type: 'capitalC'});
        await asyncCapitalFunc('A');
        await asyncCapitalFunc('B');
    };
```

The above code: In addition to the initial render, there’re two re-renders, this time it behaves the same as the click event.

```
    const batchTest = async () => {
        dispatch({type: 'capitalC'});
        await asyncCapitalFunc('A');
        await asyncCapitalFunc('B');
        await asyncCapitalFunc('D');
        await asyncCapitalFunc('E');
    };
```

The above code: Two re-renders, the first await call is batched with the dispatch above it which is as expected, but why the remaining three await calls batched together?
[Effect result3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2HgM.png)

```
    const batchTest = async () => {
        await asyncCapitalFunc('A');
        await asyncCapitalFunc('B');
        dispatch({type: 'capitalC'});
        await asyncCapitalFunc('D');
        await asyncCapitalFunc('E');
    };
```

The above code: I’m getting confused, why the await calls below "A" are all batched together…
[Effect result3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eu5hh.png)

Hope someone can explain why this quirky behavior happens in Effect, thank you.

Comment: Not sure if it has some to do with this: "The body of an async function can be thought of as being split by zero or more await expressions. Top-level code, up to and including the first await expression (if there is one), is run synchronously. In this way, an async function without an await expression will run synchronously. If there is an await expression inside the function body, however, the async function will always complete asynchronously." - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#:~:text=%3B%20//%20false-,The%20body,-of%20an%20async